Prove/disprove $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(f(x))=\lim\limits_{y\to y_0}g(y)$

Let be $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}$ and assume that both limits $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)=:y_0$ and $\lim\limits_{y\to y_0}g(y):=L$ exist. Also assume that $g\circ f$ is well defined i.e. $f([a,b])\subseteq [c,d]$.
Prove or disprove that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(f(x))=\lim\limits_{y\to y_0}g(y)$.


My approach:
Let be $(x_n)\in[a,b]$ an arbitrary sequence that converges to $x_0$. We define $(y_n)$ by $y_n:=f(x_n)$ which is a sequence in $[c,d]$ that converges to $y_0$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that
$$
g(f(x_n))=g(y_n)
$$
which directly implies $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}g(f(x_n))=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}g(y_n)$. As the sequence was chosen arbitrarily it follows $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(f(x))=\lim\limits_{y\to y_0}g(y)$.

It is quite easy to come up with counter examples that show that this statement is not true. But I would like to get some feedback on why and where my attempt is flawed.

If you know a counterexample - try to write it done, find $x_n \to x_0$ s.t. $g(f(x_n)) \not \to L$, and find which step of your prove fails.

@mihaild, the counter example doesn't violate anything so it is not helpful to find the mistake within my proof.

"$\cdots$ directly implies $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}g(f(x_n))=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}g(y_n)$."  This seems not always true.

@Philipp than how is it counterexample if it doesn't violate the statement?

@Philipp "the counter example doesn't violate anything"... Then are you sure that it is a counterexample?

@mihaild you simply consider two functions $f,g$ that are both constant except at one point. Then you can easiliy find such a sequence...

@Philipp sure, this works. Now, take such sequence, go with it through your proof, and find the first step you get a false statement.

@mihaild, sorry but I still don't understand your advice. I have already explained that the counter example produces a false result. Which means the first mistake in my proof I have found is the final result. There may be a preceding mistake (I am sure there is one) but as I have already mentioned I don't see it. Simply saying look at it again step by step doesn't quite help...

@Philipp that's correct. So, you've found sequence $y_n$ s.t. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} g(y_n) \neq \lim\limits_{y\to y_0} g(y)$. And this is the flaw: when you use Heine limit definition, there is one important condition on sequeneces to consider, besides them converging to $y_0$.

@mihaild, Ah ok I guess I get it: If we consider a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ that accidently attains $y_0$ then we can't use it for the limit definition. As I can't rule this out in my definition $y_n:=f(x_n)$ I can't use it to say something about the limit. Right? (I think anomaly's answer tried to adress this issue)

If $f(x)\neq f(x_0)$ for $x$ in some punctured neighborhood of $x_0,$ the conclusion follows. Otherwise it does not hold if $f(x_0)\neq y_0.$

Here is a simple example. Let $f, g : I \to I$, where $I = [0, 1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Define $f$ by
$$f (x) = 0$$
and $g$ by
$$g (x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x = 0 \\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Note that $h = g \circ f$ is actually identical to $f$. (*)
Now consider $x_0 = 1$. We obviously have that $y_0 = \lim_{x \to x_0} f (x) = 0$. Similarly, $L = \lim_{y \to y_0} g (y) = \lim_{y \to 0} g (y) = 1$. But $\lim_{x \to x_0} h (x) = \lim_{x \to x_0} f (x) = 0$ (where the first equality is due to the observation (*) above).
The problem is that when considering limits, we don't care about the value of the function precisely at the domain point of interest, only the behavior sufficiently close to it. There is no requirement that the function value has to equal the limit value. If we do stipulate this, however, then the statement is in fact true, and it is just the familiar fact that the composition of continuous functions is continuous.

It is not true that, as the sequence $\,(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset[a,b]\,$ that converges to $\,x_0\,$ was chosen arbitrarily, it follows that
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}g(f(x_n))\!=\!\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}g(y_n)\implies\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(f(x))\!=\!\lim\limits_{y\to y_0}g(y)\,.$
Indeed, if the function $\,f\,$ is constant, that is $\,f(x)=y_0\,$ for any $\,x\in[a,b]\,,\,$ and the function $\,g\,$ is not continuous at $\,y_0\,,$ then $\;y_n=f(x_n)=y_0\;$ and $\;g(y_n)=g(y_0)\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;$ therefore, $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(f(x_n))=g(y_0)\;,\;$ hence,
$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(f(x))=g(y_0)\quad$ but$\quad g(y_0)\neq\lim\limits_{y\to y_0}g(y)\;,$
consequently,
$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(f(x))\neq\lim\limits_{y\to y_0}g(y)\;.$
Philipp, now you know why and where your attempt is flawed, in fact in general the implication
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}g(f(x_n))\!=\!\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}g(y_n)\implies\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(f(x))\!=\!\lim\limits_{y\to y_0}g(y)$
is not correct.
